# Rename a range of columns in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to rename a range of columns in a dataframe so that they have the format [V1:V5]:

```
result_df = data.frame(V1 = 1, V2 = 2, V3 = 3, V4 = 4, V5 = 5, colnamethatshouldntberenamed = 6)
```

If the existing dataframe has the range of numbers somewhere in their names, it's relatively straigthforward (although I'm thinking there's probably a way to do it with one line of code, not two):

```
df1 = data.frame(X1q = 1, X2q = 2, X3q = 3, X4q = 4, X5q = 5, colnamethatshouldntberenamed = 6)

names(df1) <- gsub("X", "V", names(df1))
names(df1) <- gsub("q", "", names(df1))
```

But what if the column names have completely random names?

```
df2 = data.frame(name = 1, col = 2, random = 3, alsorandom = 4, somethingelse = 5, colnamethatshouldntberenamed = 6)
```

Is there a way to rename all of these columns in one-go? (assuming that they are adjoining columns in the dataframe, but there may be other columns in the dataframe with names that don't need to be changed)

Comment: do you want `names(df)[1:5] <- paste0("V", 1:5)`?

Comment: This works, @Nate. Very straightforward. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a different number of columns and/or you want to `%>%`, you can use `purrr::set_names()`.

For example:

Sample data with 10 columns:

```
example1 <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:1,5,rep=TRUE)))
example1 
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
1  1  1  0  1  1  1  0  1  0   1
2  0  0  1  0  1  1  1  0  0   1
3  0  0  1  0  0  1  1  1  0   0
4  0  1  0  1  1  0  1  0  0   0
5  1  0  0  1  1  0  1  1  0   1
```

You can use `seq_along` inside `set_names` which will rename the columns by order (with piping):

```
example1 %>% 
    set_names(c(seq_along(example1)))
```

Results:

```
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0  1
2 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0  1
3 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0  0
4 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0  0
5 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0  1
```

Same idea with 15 columns and naming them using paste in `set_names`:

```
 example2 <- data.frame(replicate(15,sample(0:1,10,rep=TRUE)))

  example2 %>% 
set_names(c(paste("VarNum", seq_along(example2), sep = "")))
```

Results

```
 VarNum1 VarNum2 VarNum3 VarNum4 VarNum5 VarNum6 VarNum7 VarNum8 VarNum9 VarNum10 VarNum11 VarNum12 VarNum13 VarNum14 VarNum15
1       0       1       0       0       0       0       0       1       1        1        1        0        1        0        1
2       1       1       0       0       0       1       0       1       1        0        0        0        1        0        1
3       1       1       0       1       0       1       1       1       1        1        1        0        1        0        1
4       0       0       0       0       1       1       1       1       0        1        1        0        0        0        1
5       1       1       0       1       0       0       1       0       0        1        1        0        0        0        0
```